# Mongoose search FindOne with Timestamp as argument

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How do I search a document in **mongoDB** collection by seracing using it timestamp?

Using *terminal* I got the deisred result :

```
db.posts.findOne({"created_at":ISODate("2016-01-20T01:28:23.825Z")})
```

But in **mongoose** how do I do this, search by time stamp

I tried putting the time in exact format(ISO) but didnt work.

```
router.get('/posts/:id', function(req, res){
        Posts.findOne({'created_at': req.params.id}, function(err, data){
            console.log(req.params.id);
            res.json(data);
        })
    })

//req.params.id = 2016-01-20T01:28:23.825Z
```

In my ***posts*** schema `created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now }`

I thought of using this with some variable :

```
 `Posts.find({'created_at': {"gte": new Date(2016, 7, 14) }}, function(err, data){}`
```

but then this will return array or simply I can add another argument for time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query your using `req.params.id` directly which is of type string. MongoDB/Mongoose don't do some magic here to convert the string to a date so your query tries to match a string against stored date values in MongoDB. To correct your issue convert `req.params.id` to a Date first:

```
router.get('/posts/:id', function(req, res){
    Posts.findOne({'created_at': new Date(req.params.id)}, function(err, data){
        console.log(req.params.id);
        res.json(data);
    })
})
```